# fstream doesn't read the input

Tags: c++

Somehow fstream doesn't read my input from a file.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("duomenys.txt");
    ofstream fout("rezultatas.txt");

    int n = 0;
    fin >> n;
    cout << n << endl;

    fout.close();
    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

duomenys.txt

> 24

The output here is 0. I can't figure out why this doesn't work..

Comment: what's in the file "duomenys.txt"?

Comment: No need to explicitly close the files. They'll be closed when `main` returns.

Comment: fstream does read input. So...

Comment: Check the state of the stream, to narrow down the problem. Almost certainly you do not have read access to a file at that path.

Comment: @larsmans The close in the destructor is a close of last resort.  At least for output, you want to check the state of the stream _after_ the close, to be sure your data has been correctly output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is relative to the process's *working directory*, which may not be the same as the executable location.

Use an absolute path to confirm that you have a path issue, and then go on to find the proper relative path to use if you wish.

Comment: If I use absolute path the output is the same. And the file is in the same directory as executable..

Comment: Pretty sure I already said that the path of the executable _has nothing to do with it_. But if an absolute path doesn't work for you either, then I can't help. Improve your error handling to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: `while (somestream.someflag()) { getline(..); dothingswithstring(); }` is almost always wrong (including here). You'll `dothingswithstring` one too many times. Put the `getline` call _in the loop condition_. **\[Another example of cplusplus.com being a site to _completely ignore_.\]**

Comment: @Marijus: Then the path is wrong, or you do not have read permissions.